# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT trigger on overflow string

Tags: mysql, sql

`GROUP_CONCAT` has it own length, and if string greater this, return value is invalid. I know, that there is setting to set more length on it

Question: is there any way to thow error instead of returning result if final string greater the limit?

Comment: When GROUP_CONCAT oversizes according sertting the warning is generated. So query `SHOW WARNINGS` for a warning with code = 1260 immediately after the query with GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: Or you can put the query into a stored procedure, and inside this procedure put an exit handler for SQL Warning. More details here [on documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-handler.html)

Comment: @Hermanto Exit handler with RESIGNAL - excellent solution.